# How can I come back to the screen I was before when navigating into another navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have the following structure:

```
  <BottomTab.Navigator>
    <BottomTab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
    <BottomTab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </BottomTab.Navigator>

  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={BottomTabsNavigator} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Article" component={ArticleScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Now, to get from Article Screen to Profile Screen, I need to go first to Tabs Navigator and from there get to Profile so I'm doing the following:

```
  navigation.navigate('Tabs', {screen: "Profile"})
```

Everything works great. The only problem that I have now is when I press back from there (Profile Screen) I would expect it to take me back to Article Screen but in fact it takes me to Tabs Navigator to Feed Screen.
Any idea how to reach the expected outcome?

What I'm doing right now is that I'm expecting on Profile Screen a route param called backRoute which is optional and if it is sent, when pressing back I go to that route, otherwise I do goBack(). This doesn't feel like the clean way to do it and it's definitely not scalable

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the back button in the profile screen and then determine his behavior depending on the screen that called it :
Something like this:

```js
<BottomTab.Screen 
     name="Profile" 
     component={ProfileScreen}
     headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => 
                if(lastScreen ==='test1'){
                 //navigate to screen 1
                 }else{
                 //navigate to screen 2  }}
               />)
          ),/>
```

To determine `lastScreen` use navigation params:

> this is the way a use with react-navigation v4 for v5 i have not
>   tested it

Comment: I'm doing something similar. I'm expecting on Profile Screen a route param called backRoute which is optional and if it is sent, when pressing back I go to that route, otherwise I do goBack()

Comment: yes, it's working but it doesn't feel like the clean way to do it and it's definitely not scalable

Comment: If you found a better solution update the post so we can learn about it. thanks